# Cómo cambiar color de background simultáneo para todos los usuarios en intervalos de tiempo

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

```js
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo) {
  var $els = $('div[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = 0,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.slice(1).hide();
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
   $("#layer6_").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
 mostrarEsconder('layer1_', 300);
});
```

```css
#layer1_1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
#layer1_2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
#layer1_3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}
#layer1_4 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
#layer1_4 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer1_1"></div>
<div id="layer1_2"></div>
<div id="layer1_3"></div>
<div id="layer1_4"></div>
<div id="layer1_5"></div>
```

Hola hay algún modo de hacer cambios de background en intervalos de tiempo que afecten de manera simultánea a todos los usuarios? Como si fuese un streaming de tal forma que si yo entro a la web cuando éste esta azul para todos los usuarios sea azul para mí y si cambia lo haga también para mí.
Muchas gracias.
**Tal vez asociándolo a una fecha concreta?**

Comment: Prueba a buscar en google websockets.

Comment: Esto permitirá aplicar los intervalos @JoseHermosillaRodrigo ? Son unos cambios fijos, yo no los ejecuto sino una función que quiero que esté activa aunque el usuario no esté en la web y cuando entra la vea en el punto en el que estaría si el estuviera, en este caso el color del background.

Comment: Para este sencillo escenario que comentas quizá no sea necesario usar websockets, voy a intentar hacer un ejemplo de lo que podrías hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo al menos así podría empezar a orientarme porque es la primera vez que meto las manos en este asunto y no sé ni por donde empezar.

Answer (score 2):

Por ejemplo podrías hacer una función que (dependiendo del minuto en este case) muestro un color. Cuando se cargue la página llamas a esa función para mostrar la página del color que le corresponde según la hora y ejecutas setInterval() para ejecutar esa función cada segundo en este caso. Esto hará que cada minuto el fondo cambie. y será para todos los usuarios igual.

```js
var fondo = document.getElementById('cuerpo');

function cambiarBackgroundPorHora (){
  var minuto =  new Date().getMinutes();
  var color;
  if(minuto < 10) color = '#FF' + minuto + 'FF' + minuto;
  else color = '#F' + minuto + 'F' + minuto;
  fondo.style.background = color;
  fondo.innerHTML = color;
}

window.onload = cambiarBackgroundPorHora;

setInterval(cambiarBackgroundPorHora, 1000);
```

```css
#cuerpo {
  width : 500px;
  height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuerpo"></div>
```

Puedes probar con los segundos para ver que el ejemplo funciona, más rápidamente :

```js
var fondo = document.getElementById('cuerpo');

function cambiarBackgroundPorHora (){
  var minuto =  new Date().getSeconds();
  var color;
  if(minuto < 10) color = '#FF' + minuto + 'FF' + minuto;
  else color = '#F' + minuto + 'F' + minuto;
  fondo.style.background = color;
  fondo.innerHTML = color;
}

window.onload = cambiarBackgroundPorHora;

setInterval(cambiarBackgroundPorHora, 1000);
```

```css
#cuerpo{
  width : 500px;
  height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuerpo"></div>
```

Comment: Es estupendo, muchas gracias, no es exactamente lo que yo necesito ya que para mí es muy importante el tema del setInterval cambiando de div... es posible ajustarlo así?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vyrdmofm/